# Save Excel file in SharePoint 2013 using javascript from out of SharePoint webpage

Tags: 2013, javascript, custom-web-app

How to save an Excel file to SharePoint 2013 from a javascript executing outside of SharePoint?

I am struggling with this issue, There were errors like

> SP is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Below is the refrence from code project as why you are getting this error:

> Sometimes you may need to execute your JavaScript (that uses ECMAScript Client OM) on page load in the browser. But since your JavaScript is using sp.js file and if the sp.js file is not loaded yet (since to lazy loading nature of sp.js), when your custom JavaScript will be executing, you’ll get your JavaScript function not executed. In this case you need to make sure your JavaScript code runs after sp.js finishes loading. You can do so by putting your JavaScript method call inside a js function as shown below:
>
> ```
> ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myjsfucntion, "sp.js");
> ```

For more info: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60348/SharePoint-2010-Client-Object-Model-for-JavaScript.aspx